# About the legalism of the Patent

Tags: us3827221

I would like to know if my patent is still valid.  I am going to make a presentation in the next couple weeks, and I want to make sure that my Patent is still valid. I want to make sure no one can legally steal my Idea......

Answer (score 1):

Your patent was issued in 1974, so looks like it expired in 1991.

Utility patents issued before June 7, 1978 only lasted 17 years. Even for newly granted ones it's only twenty years from filing.